# How to encode base64 in Delphi 6?

Tags: delphi, pdf, encoding, base64, delphi-6

I need to encode a pdf document to base64 in Delphi6.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `EncdDecd` unit that is supplied with Delphi. The function you need is `EncodeStream`. You simply need to create two streams, one for input and one for output. If you are working with files then you should create `TFileStream` instances.

Once you have your two file streams created, all you need is:

```
EncodeStream(InputStream, OutputStream);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You've been so helpful . Thank you one again

Comment: David Heffernam, can you tell me how can i see the OutputStream? I need to insert this encoded file on a Xml file

Comment: If you are adding to the XML file by means of a string, then make `OutputStream` be `TStringStream`. Read the `DataString` property of `TStringStream`.

Comment: I tried to create OutputStream as a .txt file "OutputFile:=TFileStream.Create(WOutFicheiro,fmCreate)

Comment: That will work just fine.

Comment: I tried to create OutputStream as a .txt file  "OutputFile:=TFileStream.Create(WOutFicheiro,fmCreate)" and the content of the outputfile is not the same as if I create as a TStringStream (just gives 2 characters ) "Result:= OutputFile.DataString;" - Result = String . I don´t know if I'm doing this correctly.

Comment: Well, I cannot see your code. I think I answered the question that you asked.

Comment: But how can I insert the content of my .txt file into Xml file?

Comment: That's not the question that you asked. I answered the question that you asked. As for how to put your file into your XML I've no idea. I don't know how you are working with XML. I don't know what XML lib you have. If you have another question do ask. But you should also accept an answer here because this question is answered.

Answer (score 5):

```
unit base64;

interface

uses Classes;

function base64encode(f:TStream):string;

implementation

const
  Base64Codes:array[0..63] of char=
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';

function base64encode(f:TStream):string;
const
  dSize=57*100;//must be multiple of 3
var
  d:array[0..dSize-1] of byte;
  i,l:integer;
begin
  Result:='';
  l:=dSize;
  while l=dSize do
   begin
    l:=f.Read(d[0],dSize);
    i:=0;
    while i<l do
     begin
      if i+1=l then
        Result:=Result+
          Base64Codes[  d[i  ] shr  2]+
          Base64Codes[((d[i  ] and $3) shl 4)]+
          '=='
      else if i+2=l then
        Result:=Result+
          Base64Codes[  d[i  ] shr  2]+
          Base64Codes[((d[i  ] and $3) shl 4) or (d[i+1] shr 4)]+
          Base64Codes[((d[i+1] and $F) shl 2)]+
          '='
      else
        Result:=Result+
          Base64Codes[  d[i  ] shr  2]+
          Base64Codes[((d[i  ] and $3) shl 4) or (d[i+1] shr 4)]+
          Base64Codes[((d[i+1] and $F) shl 2) or (d[i+2] shr 6)]+
          Base64Codes[  d[i+2] and $3F];
      inc(i,3);
      if ((i mod 57)=0) then Result:=Result+#13#10;
     end;
   end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: +1 for stand-alone solution.  Indy and JVCL are great, but not if you aren't already using them.

Comment: @ChrisThornton There's no need to roll your own even in D6. You can use `EncdDecd` which ships with even ancient D6.

Comment: @Stijn It would be useful to add bool parameter `linebrake` to the function for receiving one-line base64 string.
`if ((i mod 57)=0) and linebrake then Result:=Result+#13#10;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [INDY](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/wizard/DownloadWizard.EN.aspx)'s [TIdEncoderMIME](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdEncoderMIME.html) class to encode any file.

AFAIK, INDY 9 comes pre-installed in Delphi 6, but is advisable to update your INDY version as  INDY 10 is current with lot's of improvements and bug fixes over the old INDY 9.

Your code may look like this:

```
uses IdCoder, IdCoder3to4, IdCoderMIME, IdBaseComponent;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SourceStr: TFileStream;
  Encoder: TIdEncoderMIME;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    SourceStr := TFileStream.Create(OpenDialog1.FileName, fmOpenRead);
    try
      Encoder := TIdEncoderMIME.Create(nil);
      try
        Memo1.Lines.Text := Encoder.Encode(SourceStr);
      finally
        Encoder.Free;
      end;
    finally
      SourceStr.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```